# How to know if a Android device can read QR Codes?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, qr-code

Currently I have a small Activity that allows me to read QR codes and returns the string that contains the code.

I do this with ***CameraSource*** and ***SurfaceView*** from the package ***com.google.android.gms.vision*** y ***com.view*** respectively.

But I wonder if there is some way through code to know if the device that runs the application has the ability to read QR codes.

Because if the device cannot read QR codes, I would like to display a ***TextView*** instead of the ***SurfaceView*** saying that the device can't do this.

Thank you, so much.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the device has a camera. There's nothing special about reading *QR codes*; the device takes a picture, the image analysis logic does the rest.